# Google Family sharing with Google Assistant

Tags: google-assistant, google-play-family

I can't seem to figure out what data on my Google Assistant is shared with my Google Family. It looks like Google Assistant is an app that's listed with my Family according to the pages I'm reading, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what Google Assistant data is actually shared. (I'd prefer none of it be shared) I've tried contacting Google Support on this, who was terribly unhelpful.

If there's a more appropriate Google Stack Exchange forum, please let me know.